# cumulative returns based on pricing pandas dataframe

Tags: pandas

I want to calculate the cumulative returns based on prices for each stock in a pandas dataframe. the cumulative  return is current day price - price at the beginning of time (first row )in the data frame -1. How can we get this in one line ?

My dataframe is like this -

date, stock price1 , stock price2, stock_price3 and so on.

NSE         ITC
   2012-12-24  5855.750000  169.398026
   2012-12-26  5905.600098  171.433975
   2012-12-27  5870.100098  170.194687
   2012-12-28  5908.350098  170.784225
   2012-12-31  5905.100098  169.250168

i need a generic solution that I can execute and get a result in one line.

Comment: `df['new'] = df.groupby('stock')['price'].cumsum()` Change the colnames according to your dataframe. And if you want to get a detailed answer you should read this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples

Comment: I dont want to iterate over the columns. Is there any other solution ?

Comment: We need sample data. Its expensive to create datasets  on our own that match the question.

Comment: There are many solutions. Unfortunately, none without some sample data.

Comment: provided the dataset

Comment: For getting daily return I used - daily_return = (dataframe / dataframe.shift(1)) - 1 . can I do a similar thing for cumulative return ?

Comment: Please post your desired data set as well. Are you after `df.diff()` or `df.diff().cumsum()`?